# Is it possible to Use Gmail as a Sendgrid alternative for learning purposes?

Tags: gmail, sendgrid

I was searching for a mail delivery system and all the time send grid was on the top of my search and unfortunately now a days when you create a sendgrid account it is provisioned  because of spammers around the internet. I would like to have a free mail delivery system for learning purposes is there any one or can i use gmail?

Comment: Hi Naser, send me an email brandon @ sendgrid . com and I'll sort out your account

Comment: @bwest my account is now provisioned and i can send emails i have a new problem would you please help me to handle it?

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694725/i-get-a-bad-request-error-while-trying-to-send-a-message-by-sendgrid-in-asp-net